# Convert columns to datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, datetime

I am writing a csv file. Both row[3] and row[4] are date columns in my original csv file. The row[3] and row[4] are showing floats. In the csv file both of them up as integers but when I run the Python code it shows an error highlighting the decimal.

```
import csv
import xlrd
import time
import datetime

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('T:/SUNDAY REPORT 12.30.16.xlsm')
for sheet in workbook.sheets():
with open('{}.csv'.format(sheet.name), 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(sheet.row_values(row) for row in range(sheet.nrows))

print "CSV converted"

time.sleep(5)

def xldate_to_datetime(xldate):
    tempDate = datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1)
    deltaDays = datetime.timedelta(days=float(xldate)-2)
    TheTime = (tempDate + deltaDays )
    return TheTime.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

with open("InfoCenterTracker.csv","rb") as source:
    rdr= csv.reader( source )
    with open("result.csv","wb") as result:
        wtr= csv.writer( result )
        next(rdr, None) # skip the headers 
        for r in rdr:
             r[3] = xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(float(r[3]), workbook.datemode)
             r[4] = xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(float(r[4]), workbook.datemode)                 if r[1] == "": 
                 pass
             else:
                 wtr.writerow(r[1:19])

        print "Columns converted to datetime"
```

Error:

```
r[3] = xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(float(r[3]), workbook.datemode)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Values in CSV:

```
 Week(Row[3]):    Date(row[4]):
  42735.0         42730.0
  42735.0         42730.0
  42735.0         42731.0
  42735.0         42731.0
```

Comment: I have edited my original post to reflect the changes.

Comment: Have you tried `xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(int(42735.0), workbook.datemode)`?

Comment: Thanks, I have not tried that where should I have it in the snippet?

Comment: `r[3] = xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(int(r[3]), workbook.datemode)` and  `r[4] = xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(int(r[4]), workbook.datemode)`, inside the for loop.

Comment: int syntax will fail because there is a decimal present when I use float it persists with the aggravating error Abdou.  r[3] = xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(float(r[3]), workbook.datemode)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:. There has to be a way around it.

Comment: Are you sure that `r3` and `r4` are consistently numeric? You seem to have rows where those values must be empty or null. If that's the case then you will need to use `try-except` to handle them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following function to convert excel number format to datetime object

```
def xldate_to_datetime(xldate):
   tempDate = datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1)
   deltaDays = datetime.timedelta(days=int(xldate)-2)
   TheTime = (tempDate + deltaDays )
   return TheTime.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

Then change your date_format to

```
date_format = datetime.datetime.strptime(xldate_to_datetime(r[3:5][0]), "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: Thanks Imran, throws out error date_format = datetime.datetime.strptime(r[3:5][0], '%m/%d/%Y')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Week:' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'

Comment: ValueError: time data 'Week:' does not match format '%m-%d-%Y'

Comment: edited again now that I understand you had excel dates that need to be converted to actual dates

Comment: Imran Please look at the post. I excluded the beginning part because I thought it was unnecessary.

Comment: The problem is that first line of the result csv has headers so when I edit in the date_format it blows up: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Week:'

Comment: what happens if you change int to float, so deltaDays = datetime.timedelta(days=float(xldate)-2)

Comment: The same error Shijo.....ValueError: time data 'Week:' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'

Comment: skip the header row in the for loop :)  just add this line before for loop  next(rdr, None)  # skip the headers

Comment: Almost there Shijo, the csv now indicates that there is decimal: ValueError: time data '42735.0' does not match format '%m/'%d/'%Y'. THANK YOU FOR ASSISTANCE SHIJO.

Comment: Jacob, can you update your code in the question to latest and greatest so we can see whats going on

Comment: look at lines r[3] = datetime.datetime.strptime(r[3], '%m/%d/%Y')
             r[4] = datetime.datetime.strptime(r[4], '%m/%d/%Y'). You are not calling the function xldate_to_datetime(xldate). Change this to  r[3] = datetime.datetime.strptime(rxldate_to_datetime(r[3])., '%m/%d/%Y') and r[4] = datetime.datetime.strptime(rxldate_to_datetime(r[4])., '%m/%d/%Y')

Comment: Thanks Imran, the problem persists. deltaDays = datetime.timedelta(days=float(xldate)-2)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick along with Imran's code

```
r[3] = datetime.datetime.strptime(xldate_to_datetime(r[3]), "%m/%d/%Y")

r[4] = datetime.datetime.strptime(xldate_to_datetime(r[3]), "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: Thanks Shijo. It throws out an error. r[3] = datetime.datetime.strptime(r[3], '%m/%d/%Y')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Week:' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'

Comment: Can you please share you sample data ?

Comment: Attached Shijo.

Comment: 42735 what is the actual date value of this ?

Comment: The date value is 12/31/2016.

Comment: how do you say 42735 =12/31/2016

Comment: Because if I remove the datetime syntax it works fine but gives integers instead of actual dates. When I Manually open the csv and change the format to short date it alters the integer to short dates. I have edited the post to show the desired results.

Comment: Are you saying that the input file has '42735 ' and when you write to file without date formatting value is 12/31/201.. i'm confused

Comment: Please look at the original post. I excluded the beginning part because I thought it was unnecessary.

Comment: just understood that you want to do excel date calcualtion.@Imran's code is correct, just replace date_format = datetime.datetime.strptime(xldate_to_datetime(r[3:5][0]), "%m/%d/%Y")
 with       r[3] = datetime.datetime.strptime(r[3], '%m/%d/%Y')
             r[4] = datetime.datetime.strptime(r[4], '%m/%d/%Y')

Comment: Thanks Shijo, the problem is the first line of the csv has headers instead of numbers so.......ValueError: time data 'Week:' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'